# Como chamar o procedimento na Main em C#?

Tags: c#

tudo bem? Estou aprendendo a usar o C# e tenho um pouquinho de noção de programação. Estou fazendo um mini curso, mas estou tentando fazer algo mais implementado, porém não sei como, alguém pode me ajudar? Ou pelo menos explicar o que tenho que fazer? Vou por o código e abaixo falo o que quero fazer.

```
    using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Foeach
{
    internal class Aluno
    {
        private static int i;

        public static void Despedida(params string [] alunos)
        {
            foreach (string aluno in alunos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tchau {0}, até a próxima aula!", aluno);
            }
        }

        public void aluno(int i = 0, params string [] nome)
        {
            string [] array = nome;
            int opc = 0;

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
                nome[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Deseja sair? 0 - Sim, 1 - Não");
                opc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                i++;

            } while (opc != 0);
            
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int j = 0, opc = 0;

            var aluno = new Aluno();


        }


    }
}
```

O que quero fazer é: chamar o procedimento aluno na Main, cadastrar os alunos e depois usar o Despedida para dar "tchau" a todos os alunos cadastrados.

Desde já agradeço com a ajuda.

Comment: *"chamar o procedimento"* se for um *console application*, o método Main é o ponto de entrada do seu código e é chamado automaticamente: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como seu objetivo é aprender leve meu código apenas como exemplo e tente tirar o máximo proveito dele.

- Algumas alterações são necessárias para que o código funcione
  corretamente. Primeiro, precisamos registrar os alunos chamando o
  método "Aluno". Em seguida, precisamos chamar o método Despedida para
  exibir uma mensagem de despedida para cada aluno matriculado.

Abaixo está o código modificado.

```
using System;
    
    namespace Foeach
    {
        internal class Aluno
        {
            private static int i;
    
            public static void Despedida(params string[] alunos)
            {
                foreach (string aluno in alunos)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tchau {0}, até a próxima aula!", aluno);
                }
            }
    
            public void CadastrarAlunos(ref string[] nome, ref int i)
            {
                int opc = 0;
    
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                do
                {
                    Console.Write("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
                    nome[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    
                    Console.WriteLine("Deseja sair? 0 - Sim, 1 - Não");
                    opc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
                    i++;
    
                } while (opc != 0);
    
            }
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int j = 0, opc = 0;
                string[] nomes = new string[100];
                int i = 0;
    
                var aluno = new Aluno();
    
                aluno.CadastrarAlunos(ref nomes, ref i);
    
                Aluno.Despedida(nomes);
    
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

**As alterações realizadas foram:**

- Renomear o método "aluno" para "CadastrarAlunos" para melhorar a
  legibilidade do código.
- Adicionar os parâmetros "ref" ao método "CadastrarAlunos" para que as
  variáveis "nomes" e "i" sejam passadas por referência e possam ser
  alteradas dentro do método.
- Criar um array "nomes" para armazenar os nomes dos alunos.
  Inicializar a variável "i" com zero.
- Chamar o método "CadastrarAlunos" para cadastrar os alunos.
- Chamar o método "Despedida" para exibir a mensagem de despedida para
  cada aluno cadastrado.
- Adicionar um comando "Console.ReadKey()" para evitar que o programa
  termine imediatamente após a exibição da mensagem de despedida.

Comment: Cara... explicação excelente. Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda e pelo conhecimento passado. Tenho total certeza que aprendi e irei levar adiante. Tenha um ótimo ano.